# Why my add_pass function does not work? I am a newbie programmer so please don't judge

Tags: python, oop

I need help, I really dont see a problem here why my `add_pass` method does not add the arguments to the dictionary.

```py
class Password:

    def __init__(self,media,password):
        self.password = password
        self.media = media
        self.all_passwords = {}
        self.all_passwords.setdefault(self.media,self.password)   



    def add_pass(self,media,password):
        self.all_passwords[self.media] = self.password 

b = Password('instagram','pass123')
b.add_pass('fb', 'pass12345')
```

Comment: Please learn [ask]; the title in particular is not useful at all. The short answer is: because you *ignore* the arguments to it, and use attributes instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `add_pass` function, remove `self.` from `self.media` and `self.password`. Those refer to the class attributes rather than the arguments:

```
def add_pass(self,media,password):
    self.all_passwords[media] = password
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have another small question and i think you can help me. My change_pass function also has a problem. I cant see why it doesnt changes the password. The code is same from above.

Comment: def change_pass(self,media,password): |
        if password in self.all_passwords.values():|
            self.all_passwords.pop(password)|
            a = input('New password: ') |                   
            self.all_passwords[media] = a|                                                                                            sorry for bad format

Comment: @Ivan Happy to help! How about you either add that to the question or ask a new question? Also, if you found this answer correct, I'd appreciate if you marked the checkbox as accepted.